# Автоподстановка/автозамена символов в textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea, замена, keydown

Есть textarea с id = "test".

1) Как сделать так, чтобы при вводе в textarea кавычек (одинарных или двойных), подставлялась сразу пара кавычек, а курсор ставился между ними (как в средах разработки, аля sublime) ?

2) Как сделать, что если ты вводишь пару кавычек, то их в итоге не стало бы 4, а просто удалились бы вторые кавычки (и в сумме их так и осталось бы 2 -- опять же, как это реализовано в редакторах кода).

т.е. надо, чтобы было так:

' → '.' (где . -- положение курсора)

" → "."

"" → "".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделал пример работы с `"."` -- точка курсор, при вводе `"` добавляется `""`, тоже самое с одинарными кавычками, между ними курсор, но поэтому примеру можно пойти дальше, и заточить его под себя. 
Надеюсь, что помог

```js
var input = document.getElementById('test');
input.addEventListener("keypress", function(evt){
if(evt.which === 34)
{
 input.value = input.value + "\"";
 setCaretPosition(input, input.value.lastIndexOf('"'))
}
 if(evt.which === 39)
{
 input.value = input.value + "'";
 console.log(input.value.lastIndexOf("'"))
 setCaretPosition(input, input.value.lastIndexOf("'"))
}

})

function setCaretPosition(elem, caretPos) {
var range;

if (elem.createTextRange) {
    range = elem.createTextRange();
    range.move('character', caretPos);
    range.select();
} else {
    elem.focus();
    if (elem.selectionStart !== undefined) {
        elem.setSelectionRange(caretPos, caretPos);
    }
}
}
```

```html
<textarea id="test"></textarea>
```

Comment: Спасибо, как раз то, что нужно!